# How can I stream music from a different machine?

Tags: remote

I have a Raspberry Pi connected to a sound system via the jack output. I'd like that the output of the sound card of my laptop was redirected to the Raspberry Pi.

I have read about mplayer daemon or icecast protocol but I don't really know how to make it work.

Comment: Laptop running Windows or Linux?

Comment: Linux, based on debian

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend using pulseaudio for this, if you don't want to setup shairport and RAOP. [The pulseaudio documentation](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/PulseAudio/Documentation/User/Network/#index2h3) describes how you can do this. You need to setup your debian laptop to provide a pulseaudio rtp sink. There is also [a nice howto](http://fruit.je/mpd-rtp) available on mpd and pulseaudio.

For some first tests, you can just run these commands through `pacmd` on your laptop to set up an rtp sink:

```
load-module module-null-sink sink_name=rtp
load-module module-rtp-send source=rtp.monitor
set-default-sink rtp
```

On the Pi, you will need to start the rtp receiver:

```
load-module module-rtp-recv
```

You can do this also via `pacmd` and put it later into a configuration file.

Answer (score 0):

Raspi jack output has poor audio quality, you might be better off connecting your audio system directly to the laptop output or somehow use HDMI output if possible.

Comment: My laptop can't be near my audio system and I can't use HDMI output. I already tried the jack output and the quality is good enough for what I want to do.

Answer (score 0):

I think Shareport would do what you want to do - http://www.raspberrypi.org/phpBB3/viewtopic.php?f=38&t=41504
https://github.com/lukstei/shairport

Comment: I was thinking about something lighter